# How do I edit the symbol (a \star in the \box) by LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

In LaTeX there exists a symbol `$\boxplus$` but how do I type the symbol "a star in a box"?

Comment: try $\boxtimes$

Comment: The symbol is `\boxast`, which requires `\usepackage{stmaryrd}`. See table 52 in the comprehensive list.

Comment: I want to type$\star$ not $\times$